# How to pass a parameter in C++ with the help of "=" operator

Tags: c++, methods, parameters, operator-overloading

I have a class named `Demo` and in that class I have overloaded the `Text()` method for setting and getting it's private variable called `text`.

```
#ifndef DEMO_H
#define DEMO_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Demo {
    string text;

public:
    Demo() {};
    Demo(string newText) : text(newText) {};
    void Text(string updatedText);
    string Text();
};
#endif // !DEMO_H


void Demo::Text(string updatedText) {
    text = updatedText;
}

string Demo::Text() {
    return text;
}
```

Then in another class, I have used the method in following way-

```
#include "Demo.h"

int main()
{
    Demo d;
    d.Text("test");
    cout << d.Text() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine. However, I want to set the parameter of the method with "=" operator. So rather than

```
d.Text("test");
```

I want to do

```
d.Text = "test";
```

Is it possible to achieve in C++ and if so then how. I was thinking of operator overloading but I couldn't achieve the goal. Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: you could have public member `std::string Text;`

Comment: Warning: That would be realllly unidiomatic C++.

Comment: I know that but I don't want that. This is just an example. I want to achieve the mechanism of parameter passing with the assignment operator.

Comment: You would have to make a public data member called `Text` whose type is a class you write that has overloaded assignment operator (or possibly implicit conversion to `std::string&` operator)

Comment: I assume you already know how to use operator overloading? Can you be more specific about what you're thinking about, and where are you stuck at?

Comment: Ever heard of the term "property"? Use it. Don't make up terms like "with the help of “=” operator" that no one likes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)

Comment: @Natasha C++ doesn't have an equivalent of _properties_ like c# actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ some C++ compilers offer properties as a non-standard syntax extension; and I think since C++11 it is possible to code them

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get in c++ to express *property* like getter / setter functions similar as in c# is to provide class member functions like these:

```
class Demo {
    string text;

public:
    void Text(const string& updatedText) { text = updatedText; }
    const string& Text() const { return text; } 
};
```

That idiom is used a lot in the c++ standard library like [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags).

---

> I want to do
>
> ```
> d.Text = "test";
> ```

What you can do is

```
class Demo {
public:
    string& Text() { return text; }
};
```

and

```
d.Text() = "test";
```

but that totally defeats the concept of encapsulation of data.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to proceed is overloading the assignment '=' operator and use as below.

```
class Demo {
    string text;

public:
    Demo() {};
    Demo(string newText) : text(newText) {};
    **void operator =(const string& val) { text = val; }**
    void Text(string updatedText);
    string Text();
};

int main()
{
    Demo d;
    //d.Text("test");
    d = "hello world";
    cout << d.Text() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your `Text` property as an object `T`. `T` could then overload some common property operations ( haven't figured out how a common getter call like  `Object o; o.set(d.Text);` would be implemented yet ) :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class T {
    string _text;
public:
    void operator =(const string& t) { _text = t; }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& obj)
    {
      cout << obj._text;
      return os;
    }
};

class Demo {
public:
    T Text;
};

int main()
{
    Demo d;
    d.Text = "test";
    cout << d.Text << endl;
}
```